# PHP: Getting unique combinations of numbers from an array

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a lists of possible combination for multiplication of 4 randomly selected numbers from an array of prime numbers to no avail. Any pointers?

Its quite a direct approach and i feel there's something i carelessly missed.
here's what i've been stucked with:

```
//Pruning outcome from controlled lists of Prime Numbers
$primes = array(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21);

function getUniqueRandomProductsWithNumbers($arr, $n) {
  $seen = array(); // Store seen combinations to avoid duplicates
  $productsWithNumbers = array();

  while (count($productsWithNumbers) < pow(count($arr), $n)) {
    $selected = array_rand($arr, $n); // Get random indexes
    sort($selected); // Sort to ensure order for checking duplicates
    $key = implode(",", $selected); // Create a unique key based on sorted indexes

    if (!isset($seen[$key])) {
      $product = 1;
      $numbers = array();
      foreach ($selected as $i) {
        $product *= $arr[$i];
        $numbers[] = $arr[$i];
      }
      $seen[$key] = true;
      $productsWithNumbers[] = array($numbers, $product);
    }
  }

  return $productsWithNumbers;
}

$uniqueProducts = getUniqueRandomProductsWithNumbers($primes, 4);
echo "Unique Products with Numbers:\n";
foreach ($uniqueProducts as $productSet) {
  echo "Numbers: ";
  print_r($productSet[0]); // Print the numbers array
  echo ", Product: " . $productSet[1] . "\n";
}
```

Really appreciate any pointers. Thanx in advance...