# Accumulate all combinations of a subset of numbers from a flat array to generate a 2d array of combinations and their product

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, combinations

I have a function that takes randomly take 4 unique numbers from an array and multiply them. Problem with the script below is it only print out the products. I would like for each set of 4 numbers and its product to be in its own array and all the arrays into a main array, forming a 2 dimensional array.

My current script:

```
//Pruning outcome from controlled lists of Prime Numbers
$primes = array(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23);


function getAllCombinations($arr, $n, $selected = array(), $startIndex = 0) {
  if ($n == 0) {
    $product = 1;
    foreach ($selected as $prime) {
      $pr[] = $prime;
      $product *= $prime;
      $pr[] = $prime;
    }
    echo "Product: $product\n";
    return;
  }

  for ($i = $startIndex; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $selected[] = $arr[$i];
    getAllCombinations($arr, $n - 1, $selected, $i + 1);
    array_pop($selected); // Backtrack and remove the element for next iteration
  }
}  

getAllCombinations($primes, 4);
```

Instead of using echo resulting as :

```
Product: 210 Product: 330 Product: 390 Product: 510,
```

I would prefer them to be in 2 dimensional array so that each row is the combination of numbers with the product as the last element in the row:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 2,
    1 => 3,
    2 => 5,
    3 => 7,
    4 => 210,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 2,
    1 => 3,
    2 => 5,
    3 => 11,
    4 => 330,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 2,
    1 => 3,
    2 => 5,
    3 => 13,
    4 => 390,
  ),
  ...
)
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the values into an array and returning that array variable?

Comment: Please post an example of what your desired result array would look like.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer yes i have tried several method but each left me more baffled than before. I guess my fundamentals are still way off.

Comment: instead of output like Product: 210 Product: 330 Product: 390 Product: 510, i would prefer them to be in 2 dimensional array like: [0][0] =>2 [0][1] =>3 [0][2]=>5 [0][3]=>7 and the product would be in [0][4] =>210

Comment: [edit] your question please if you have new examples or other information for us, then a) it can be formatted in a readable way and b) it makes your question clear and coherent all in one place, not scattered around various comments - this site isn't like a discussion forum, as I'm sure you know. Thanks.

Comment: [1][0] =>2 [1][1] =>3 [1][2]=>5 [1][3]=>11 and the product would be in [1][4] =>330 so on and so forth

Comment: Again please **edit your question** with your new information. Reminder: [ask]. Thankyou.

Comment: [Asker's previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78141707/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this may be what you are trying to do.

PHP:

```
<?php
$primes = array(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23);

// Create array to hold the combinations and their products
$allCombinations = [];

function getAllCombinations($arr, $n, &$allCombinations, $selected = array(), $startIndex = 0) {
    if ($n == 0) {
        $product = 1;
        foreach ($selected as $prime) {
            $product *= $prime;
        }
        // Add each combination and its product to the $allCombinations array
        $selected[] = $product;
        $allCombinations[] = $selected;
        return;
    }

    for ($i = $startIndex; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $selected[] = $arr[$i];
        getAllCombinations($arr, $n - 1, $allCombinations, $selected, $i + 1);
        array_pop($selected);
    }
}  

getAllCombinations($primes, 4, $allCombinations);

// To view the result
foreach ($allCombinations as $index => $combination) {
    $textRepresentation = "";

    // loop through each element in the combination
    foreach ($combination as $innerIndex => $value) {
        // add the current element's index and value
        if ($innerIndex < count($combination) - 1) { // for elements before the product
            $textRepresentation .= "[$index][$innerIndex] => $value ";
        } else { // for the product
            $textRepresentation .= "and the product would be in [$index][$innerIndex] => $value";
        }
    }

    echo $textRepresentation . "<br>";
}

?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
[0][0] => 2 [0][1] => 3 [0][2] => 5 [0][3] => 7 and the product would be in [0][4] => 210
[1][0] => 2 [1][1] => 3 [1][2] => 5 [1][3] => 11 and the product would be in [1][4] => 330
[2][0] => 2 [2][1] => 3 [2][2] => 5 [2][3] => 13 and the product would be in [2][4] => 390
[3][0] => 2 [3][1] => 3 [3][2] => 5 [3][3] => 17 and the product would be in [3][4] => 510
[4][0] => 2 [4][1] => 3 [4][2] => 5 [4][3] => 19 and the product would be in [4][4] => 570
[5][0] => 2 [5][1] => 3 [5][2] => 5 [5][3] => 23 and the product would be in [5][4] => 690
[6][0] => 2 [6][1] => 3 [6][2] => 7 [6][3] => 11 and the product would be in [6][4] => 462
[7][0] => 2 [7][1] => 3 [7][2] => 7 [7][3] => 13 and the product would be in [7][4] => 546
[8][0] => 2 [8][1] => 3 [8][2] => 7 [8][3] => 17 and the product would be in [8][4] => 714
[9][0] => 2 [9][1] => 3 [9][2] => 7 [9][3] => 19 and the product would be in [9][4] => 798
[10][0] => 2 [10][1] => 3 [10][2] => 7 [10][3] => 23 and the product would be in [10][4] => 966
[11][0] => 2 [11][1] => 3 [11][2] => 11 [11][3] => 13 and the product would be in [11][4] => 858
[12][0] => 2 [12][1] => 3 [12][2] => 11 [12][3] => 17 and the product would be in [12][4] => 1122
[13][0] => 2 [13][1] => 3 [13][2] => 11 [13][3] => 19 and the product would be in [13][4] => 1254
[14][0] => 2 [14][1] => 3 [14][2] => 11 [14][3] => 23 and the product would be in [14][4] => 1518
[15][0] => 2 [15][1] => 3 [15][2] => 13 [15][3] => 17 and the product would be in [15][4] => 1326
[16][0] => 2 [16][1] => 3 [16][2] => 13 [16][3] => 19 and the product would be in [16][4] => 1482
[17][0] => 2 [17][1] => 3 [17][2] => 13 [17][3] => 23 and the product would be in [17][4] => 1794
[18][0] => 2 [18][1] => 3 [18][2] => 17 [18][3] => 19 and the product would be in [18][4] => 1938
[19][0] => 2 [19][1] => 3 [19][2] => 17 [19][3] => 23 and the product would be in [19][4] => 2346
[20][0] => 2 [20][1] => 3 [20][2] => 19 [20][3] => 23 and the product would be in [20][4] => 2622
[21][0] => 2 [21][1] => 5 [21][2] => 7 [21][3] => 11 and the product would be in [21][4] => 770
[22][0] => 2 [22][1] => 5 [22][2] => 7 [22][3] => 13 and the product would be in [22][4] => 910
[23][0] => 2 [23][1] => 5 [23][2] => 7 [23][3] => 17 and the product would be in [23][4] => 1190
[24][0] => 2 [24][1] => 5 [24][2] => 7 [24][3] => 19 and the product would be in [24][4] => 1330
[25][0] => 2 [25][1] => 5 [25][2] => 7 [25][3] => 23 and the product would be in [25][4] => 1610
[26][0] => 2 [26][1] => 5 [26][2] => 11 [26][3] => 13 and the product would be in [26][4] => 1430
[27][0] => 2 [27][1] => 5 [27][2] => 11 [27][3] => 17 and the product would be in [27][4] => 1870
[28][0] => 2 [28][1] => 5 [28][2] => 11 [28][3] => 19 and the product would be in [28][4] => 2090
[29][0] => 2 [29][1] => 5 [29][2] => 11 [29][3] => 23 and the product would be in [29][4] => 2530
[30][0] => 2 [30][1] => 5 [30][2] => 13 [30][3] => 17 and the product would be in [30][4] => 2210
[31][0] => 2 [31][1] => 5 [31][2] => 13 [31][3] => 19 and the product would be in [31][4] => 2470
[32][0] => 2 [32][1] => 5 [32][2] => 13 [32][3] => 23 and the product would be in [32][4] => 2990
[33][0] => 2 [33][1] => 5 [33][2] => 17 [33][3] => 19 and the product would be in [33][4] => 3230
[34][0] => 2 [34][1] => 5 [34][2] => 17 [34][3] => 23 and the product would be in [34][4] => 3910
[35][0] => 2 [35][1] => 5 [35][2] => 19 [35][3] => 23 and the product would be in [35][4] => 4370
[36][0] => 2 [36][1] => 7 [36][2] => 11 [36][3] => 13 and the product would be in [36][4] => 2002
[37][0] => 2 [37][1] => 7 [37][2] => 11 [37][3] => 17 and the product would be in [37][4] => 2618
[38][0] => 2 [38][1] => 7 [38][2] => 11 [38][3] => 19 and the product would be in [38][4] => 2926
[39][0] => 2 [39][1] => 7 [39][2] => 11 [39][3] => 23 and the product would be in [39][4] => 3542
[40][0] => 2 [40][1] => 7 [40][2] => 13 [40][3] => 17 and the product would be in [40][4] => 3094
[41][0] => 2 [41][1] => 7 [41][2] => 13 [41][3] => 19 and the product would be in [41][4] => 3458
[42][0] => 2 [42][1] => 7 [42][2] => 13 [42][3] => 23 and the product would be in [42][4] => 4186
[43][0] => 2 [43][1] => 7 [43][2] => 17 [43][3] => 19 and the product would be in [43][4] => 4522
[44][0] => 2 [44][1] => 7 [44][2] => 17 [44][3] => 23 and the product would be in [44][4] => 5474
[45][0] => 2 [45][1] => 7 [45][2] => 19 [45][3] => 23 and the product would be in [45][4] => 6118
[46][0] => 2 [46][1] => 11 [46][2] => 13 [46][3] => 17 and the product would be in [46][4] => 4862
[47][0] => 2 [47][1] => 11 [47][2] => 13 [47][3] => 19 and the product would be in [47][4] => 5434
[48][0] => 2 [48][1] => 11 [48][2] => 13 [48][3] => 23 and the product would be in [48][4] => 6578
[49][0] => 2 [49][1] => 11 [49][2] => 17 [49][3] => 19 and the product would be in [49][4] => 7106
[50][0] => 2 [50][1] => 11 [50][2] => 17 [50][3] => 23 and the product would be in [50][4] => 8602
[51][0] => 2 [51][1] => 11 [51][2] => 19 [51][3] => 23 and the product would be in [51][4] => 9614
[52][0] => 2 [52][1] => 13 [52][2] => 17 [52][3] => 19 and the product would be in [52][4] => 8398
[53][0] => 2 [53][1] => 13 [53][2] => 17 [53][3] => 23 and the product would be in [53][4] => 10166
[54][0] => 2 [54][1] => 13 [54][2] => 19 [54][3] => 23 and the product would be in [54][4] => 11362
[55][0] => 2 [55][1] => 17 [55][2] => 19 [55][3] => 23 and the product would be in [55][4] => 14858
[56][0] => 3 [56][1] => 5 [56][2] => 7 [56][3] => 11 and the product would be in [56][4] => 1155
[57][0] => 3 [57][1] => 5 [57][2] => 7 [57][3] => 13 and the product would be in [57][4] => 1365
[58][0] => 3 [58][1] => 5 [58][2] => 7 [58][3] => 17 and the product would be in [58][4] => 1785
[59][0] => 3 [59][1] => 5 [59][2] => 7 [59][3] => 19 and the product would be in [59][4] => 1995
[60][0] => 3 [60][1] => 5 [60][2] => 7 [60][3] => 23 and the product would be in [60][4] => 2415
[61][0] => 3 [61][1] => 5 [61][2] => 11 [61][3] => 13 and the product would be in [61][4] => 2145
[62][0] => 3 [62][1] => 5 [62][2] => 11 [62][3] => 17 and the product would be in [62][4] => 2805
[63][0] => 3 [63][1] => 5 [63][2] => 11 [63][3] => 19 and the product would be in [63][4] => 3135
[64][0] => 3 [64][1] => 5 [64][2] => 11 [64][3] => 23 and the product would be in [64][4] => 3795
[65][0] => 3 [65][1] => 5 [65][2] => 13 [65][3] => 17 and the product would be in [65][4] => 3315
[66][0] => 3 [66][1] => 5 [66][2] => 13 [66][3] => 19 and the product would be in [66][4] => 3705
[67][0] => 3 [67][1] => 5 [67][2] => 13 [67][3] => 23 and the product would be in [67][4] => 4485
[68][0] => 3 [68][1] => 5 [68][2] => 17 [68][3] => 19 and the product would be in [68][4] => 4845
[69][0] => 3 [69][1] => 5 [69][2] => 17 [69][3] => 23 and the product would be in [69][4] => 5865
[70][0] => 3 [70][1] => 5 [70][2] => 19 [70][3] => 23 and the product would be in [70][4] => 6555
[71][0] => 3 [71][1] => 7 [71][2] => 11 [71][3] => 13 and the product would be in [71][4] => 3003
[72][0] => 3 [72][1] => 7 [72][2] => 11 [72][3] => 17 and the product would be in [72][4] => 3927
[73][0] => 3 [73][1] => 7 [73][2] => 11 [73][3] => 19 and the product would be in [73][4] => 4389
[74][0] => 3 [74][1] => 7 [74][2] => 11 [74][3] => 23 and the product would be in [74][4] => 5313
[75][0] => 3 [75][1] => 7 [75][2] => 13 [75][3] => 17 and the product would be in [75][4] => 4641
[76][0] => 3 [76][1] => 7 [76][2] => 13 [76][3] => 19 and the product would be in [76][4] => 5187
[77][0] => 3 [77][1] => 7 [77][2] => 13 [77][3] => 23 and the product would be in [77][4] => 6279
[78][0] => 3 [78][1] => 7 [78][2] => 17 [78][3] => 19 and the product would be in [78][4] => 6783
[79][0] => 3 [79][1] => 7 [79][2] => 17 [79][3] => 23 and the product would be in [79][4] => 8211
[80][0] => 3 [80][1] => 7 [80][2] => 19 [80][3] => 23 and the product would be in [80][4] => 9177
[81][0] => 3 [81][1] => 11 [81][2] => 13 [81][3] => 17 and the product would be in [81][4] => 7293
[82][0] => 3 [82][1] => 11 [82][2] => 13 [82][3] => 19 and the product would be in [82][4] => 8151
[83][0] => 3 [83][1] => 11 [83][2] => 13 [83][3] => 23 and the product would be in [83][4] => 9867
[84][0] => 3 [84][1] => 11 [84][2] => 17 [84][3] => 19 and the product would be in [84][4] => 10659
[85][0] => 3 [85][1] => 11 [85][2] => 17 [85][3] => 23 and the product would be in [85][4] => 12903
[86][0] => 3 [86][1] => 11 [86][2] => 19 [86][3] => 23 and the product would be in [86][4] => 14421
[87][0] => 3 [87][1] => 13 [87][2] => 17 [87][3] => 19 and the product would be in [87][4] => 12597
[88][0] => 3 [88][1] => 13 [88][2] => 17 [88][3] => 23 and the product would be in [88][4] => 15249
[89][0] => 3 [89][1] => 13 [89][2] => 19 [89][3] => 23 and the product would be in [89][4] => 17043
[90][0] => 3 [90][1] => 17 [90][2] => 19 [90][3] => 23 and the product would be in [90][4] => 22287
[91][0] => 5 [91][1] => 7 [91][2] => 11 [91][3] => 13 and the product would be in [91][4] => 5005
[92][0] => 5 [92][1] => 7 [92][2] => 11 [92][3] => 17 and the product would be in [92][4] => 6545
[93][0] => 5 [93][1] => 7 [93][2] => 11 [93][3] => 19 and the product would be in [93][4] => 7315
[94][0] => 5 [94][1] => 7 [94][2] => 11 [94][3] => 23 and the product would be in [94][4] => 8855
[95][0] => 5 [95][1] => 7 [95][2] => 13 [95][3] => 17 and the product would be in [95][4] => 7735
[96][0] => 5 [96][1] => 7 [96][2] => 13 [96][3] => 19 and the product would be in [96][4] => 8645
[97][0] => 5 [97][1] => 7 [97][2] => 13 [97][3] => 23 and the product would be in [97][4] => 10465
[98][0] => 5 [98][1] => 7 [98][2] => 17 [98][3] => 19 and the product would be in [98][4] => 11305
[99][0] => 5 [99][1] => 7 [99][2] => 17 [99][3] => 23 and the product would be in [99][4] => 13685
[100][0] => 5 [100][1] => 7 [100][2] => 19 [100][3] => 23 and the product would be in [100][4] => 15295
[101][0] => 5 [101][1] => 11 [101][2] => 13 [101][3] => 17 and the product would be in [101][4] => 12155
[102][0] => 5 [102][1] => 11 [102][2] => 13 [102][3] => 19 and the product would be in [102][4] => 13585
[103][0] => 5 [103][1] => 11 [103][2] => 13 [103][3] => 23 and the product would be in [103][4] => 16445
[104][0] => 5 [104][1] => 11 [104][2] => 17 [104][3] => 19 and the product would be in [104][4] => 17765
[105][0] => 5 [105][1] => 11 [105][2] => 17 [105][3] => 23 and the product would be in [105][4] => 21505
[106][0] => 5 [106][1] => 11 [106][2] => 19 [106][3] => 23 and the product would be in [106][4] => 24035
[107][0] => 5 [107][1] => 13 [107][2] => 17 [107][3] => 19 and the product would be in [107][4] => 20995
[108][0] => 5 [108][1] => 13 [108][2] => 17 [108][3] => 23 and the product would be in [108][4] => 25415
[109][0] => 5 [109][1] => 13 [109][2] => 19 [109][3] => 23 and the product would be in [109][4] => 28405
[110][0] => 5 [110][1] => 17 [110][2] => 19 [110][3] => 23 and the product would be in [110][4] => 37145
[111][0] => 7 [111][1] => 11 [111][2] => 13 [111][3] => 17 and the product would be in [111][4] => 17017
[112][0] => 7 [112][1] => 11 [112][2] => 13 [112][3] => 19 and the product would be in [112][4] => 19019
[113][0] => 7 [113][1] => 11 [113][2] => 13 [113][3] => 23 and the product would be in [113][4] => 23023
[114][0] => 7 [114][1] => 11 [114][2] => 17 [114][3] => 19 and the product would be in [114][4] => 24871
[115][0] => 7 [115][1] => 11 [115][2] => 17 [115][3] => 23 and the product would be in [115][4] => 30107
[116][0] => 7 [116][1] => 11 [116][2] => 19 [116][3] => 23 and the product would be in [116][4] => 33649
[117][0] => 7 [117][1] => 13 [117][2] => 17 [117][3] => 19 and the product would be in [117][4] => 29393
[118][0] => 7 [118][1] => 13 [118][2] => 17 [118][3] => 23 and the product would be in [118][4] => 35581
[119][0] => 7 [119][1] => 13 [119][2] => 19 [119][3] => 23 and the product would be in [119][4] => 39767
[120][0] => 7 [120][1] => 17 [120][2] => 19 [120][3] => 23 and the product would be in [120][4] => 52003
[121][0] => 11 [121][1] => 13 [121][2] => 17 [121][3] => 19 and the product would be in [121][4] => 46189
[122][0] => 11 [122][1] => 13 [122][2] => 17 [122][3] => 23 and the product would be in [122][4] => 55913
[123][0] => 11 [123][1] => 13 [123][2] => 19 [123][3] => 23 and the product would be in [123][4] => 62491
[124][0] => 11 [124][1] => 17 [124][2] => 19 [124][3] => 23 and the product would be in [124][4] => 81719
[125][0] => 13 [125][1] => 17 [125][2] => 19 [125][3] => 23 and the product would be in [125][4] => 96577
```

Comment: yes... thats what i wanted. Just a question. function getAllCombinations(... &$allCombinations,...) {
What is the purpose of the '&' preceeding $allCombinations?

Comment: @JoeShamuraq Adding the '&' means we are passing $allCombinations by reference which means the function is modifying the original array outside of the function - ensuring the changes made inside the function are reflected in the original array.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the elegance of not defining a reference variable to collect all of the results.  Instead, I've refactored your script to return the result array.

I've used `...` (spread operator) to allow the accumulation of payloads without deviating from the desired 2d structure.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Hau5L))

```
function getAllCombinations(array $arr, int $n, array $selected = [], int $startIndex = 0): array
{
    if (!$n) {
        return [array_merge($selected, [array_product($selected)])]; // generate payload
    }

    $result = [];
    $count = count($arr);
    for ($i = $startIndex; $i < $count; ++$i) {
        array_push(
            $result,
            ...getAllCombinations($arr, $n - 1, array_merge($selected, [$arr[$i]]), $i + 1)
        );
    }
    return $result;
}

$primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23];
var_export(getAllCombinations($primes, 4));
```