# Replace last value in each row of a 2d array with the product of all values in the row excluding the last

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, subset, multiplication

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 [3] => 7 [4] => 210 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 9 [2] => 5 [3] => 7 [4] => 210 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 9 [2] => 25 [3] => 7 [4] => 210 ) )
```

I would like to replace the last entry of each array with the product of the values from its preceding elements. For example,

```
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 [3] => 7 [4] => 210 )
```

Would actually be:

```
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 [3] => 7 [4] => 420 )
```

How do I delete that last element and multiply the preceding elements and fill in the correct value as the last element?

I tried reading about `array_splice()`, but do not understand the integer they used eg; `array_splice($input, 1, -1);`

Comment: The [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) are pretty clear on what the negative number means. "If length is specified and is negative, then the end of the removed portion will be that many elements from the end of the array.

"

Comment: you don't need to delete the last element, just change its value to `$total` which can be calculated using a `for` loop. personally i like to delete last items with `array_pop`

Comment: @Joe didn't you see my [use of `array_product()` on your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78143571/2943403)?  Why are you encountering this problem in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

A compact solution: *array_walk()* processes every row of the main array, the callable receives the sub-array as reference, removes the last element, calculates the product of all remaining elements using *array_reduce()* and assigns it as the last element of the sub-array.

```php
<?php

$mainArray = [
    
    [4, 3, 5, 7, 210],
    [4, 9, 5, 7, 210],
    [4, 9, 25, 7, 210],
];


array_walk ($mainArray, function (&$subArr) {
                           array_pop($subArr);
                           $subArr[] = !$subArr ? 0 : array_reduce($subArr, fn ($carry, $item) => $carry * $item, 1);
                        },
);


print_r ($mainArray);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 420
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 1260
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 25
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 6300
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you iterate the rows, isolate all but the last element and multiply them.  Overwrite the last element with that product. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZDk6B))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function($row) {
            $row[array_key_last($row)] = array_product(array_slice($row, 0, -1));
            return $row;
        },
        $array
    )
);
```

Or multiply everything, then divide by the popped-off element: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NmR2h))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function($row) {
            $row[] = array_product($row) / array_pop($row);
            return $row;
        },
        $array
    )
);
```

Or remove the last element before multiplying ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XEKpC))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function($row) {
            array_pop($row);
            $row[] = array_product($row);
            return $row;
        },
        $array
    )
);
```

Or enjoy arrow function syntax by uniting the product to the modified row: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RDqtT))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => $row + [array_key_last($row) => array_product($row) / array_pop($row)],
        $array
    )
);
```

Or modify by reference using a classic loop: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5pU3W))

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    array_pop($row);
    $row[] = array_product($row);
}
var_export($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The array_splice() function in PHP is used to remove a portion of an array and replace it with something else.

Example given ,array_splice($input, 1, -1,[new_element])

$input: The input array.

1: The index at which to start the operation. In this case, it's 1, meaning the second element of each sub-array.

-1: The length of the portion to remove. A negative length means that the end of the array will be used as the length. So, -1 means everything from the start index to the end of the array.

[new_element]: Optional. An array containing the new element to insert into the array.

So, if you want to remove the last element of each sub-array and replace it with the product of the preceding elements, you could do something like this:

```
$arrays = [
    [4, 3, 5, 7, 210],
    [4, 9, 5, 7, 210],
    [4, 9, 25, 7, 210]
];

foreach ($arrays as &$array) {
    // Calculate the product of the first n-1 elements
    $product = array_product(array_slice($array, 0, -1));
    
    // Replace the last element with the product
    array_splice($array, -1, 1, $product);
}

// Output the modified arrays
print_r($arrays);
```

This code will produce the desired output, replacing the last element of each sub-array with the product of its preceding elements.

Comment: All answers from this user are AI generated.

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?